# How should very large but highly symmetric arrays be handled in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, sparse-matrix, large-data

I am trying to populate and store a NumPy array with ~1 trillion entries with data to be retrieved later. The array has ~50 dimensions with ~7 indices, i.e. it is a rank-7 tensor in 50 dimensions or an array of shape (50,50,50,50,50,50,50). However, the data is totally symmetric meaning that most of the array is redundant. Concretely, an element is 0 whenever an index is repeated, and elements related through any index permutation are always equal. This implies that there are only 50-choose-7 or ~100 million unique, non-zero elements.

The issue is that I lack the RAM to even initialize an empty array large enough to store the data. I could certainly handle an array with only 100 million entries, but I don't know how I would go about doing that.

I have a strong math background, but I am fairly inexperienced with programming. I know that there should be a way to use hard-disk memory to supplement the RAM, but I am confident that I do not have the disk space to accommodate the overflow anyway. I am sure that there is probably a math trick to relate the large, symmetric matrix to a smaller, non-symmetric matrix, but I can't find anything about that anywhere. I would also guess that there is a way to use a sparse matrix data structure to work around the RAM limitations so that the program knows that I won't need the whole thing ahead of time, but I do not understand most of what I find about this -- it doesn't even seem to me that the sorts of sparse matrix applications I am finding apply to this scenario.

I suspect that my inexperience is leading me to use the wrong terminology in my searches and to misunderstand the solutions that I do find.

**So what is the best way to manage data of this sort in Python?**

Comment: Manipulate how? Choice of representation really depends what kind of operations you want to perform.

Comment: @Ry Sure, I mainly want to be able to retrieve the data later. I was trying to make the question generalizable because I am pretty lost, and it didn't occur to be that that might make it unanswerable. I'll edit it now.

Comment: See [squareform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html) for SciPy's solution to this problem for 2D symmetric matrices. It sounds like you have more dimensions than a 2D matrix? Can you provide more information about the number of dimensions? Edit: NVM, I can't read.

Comment: @NickODell Yes, I thought I made this clear in the question, but it is a tensor with 7-indices (so, like a 7-dimensional matrix) with about 50 components along each of those "dimensions". I would normally call this a rank-7 tensor in 50 dimensions. I'll edit the question to clear this up.

Comment: How many non-zero elements are there in total? Perhaps you could use [scipy.sparse](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html).

Comment: This is still *relatively* inefficient, but you can use any key/value structure where the key is an order-independent function of the indexes, e.g. a tuple of the indexes in ascending order, or an integer where the set bits correspond to the indexes (a bitset).

Comment: @NickODell The vast majority of the entries are non-zero, but  only about 1 in every 10,000 is unique. It is essentially an upper triangular matrix in 7 dimensions, which is why the unique entries total 50-choose-7 as I mention in the question.

Comment: @NickODell If you can explain how to apply scipy.sparse to this problem, I would welsome the answer since that could potentially solve the issue entirely.

Comment: @Ry Yes, this makes sense to me.  I think that it is the same idea behind the answer from J_H.

Comment: Symmetry is most commonly implemented in a 2d context, and even there `numpy` is most useful if those values are mapped on to a ckndensed 1d array.  Similarly scipy.sparse is 2d, (with only 5% nonzero values).  So extending either to 7d will be a stretch - conceptually as well as practically.

Comment: It is not clear to me what are the exact symmetries. Upper triangular matrices are well defined but AFAIK there is no generalisation to N-dimentional array. If so what would it be. Is the array symmetric in any possible axis?

Comment: It is a bit hard to visualize/imagine already in 3D, but assuming this is the case (highly symmetric), then the number of replicated items should be >50**7/2**7. This means >45 GiB array if you use a `float64` datatype. Unless you do all operations in-place (not done by default), you need certainly >90 GiB of RAM which is quite huge already.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yes, that's right. It is "upper triangular" in the sense that if you only listed the *unique* entries, they would fit in the indices of $M_{abcdijk}$ where $a<b<c<d<i<j<k$. My background is physics and there the phrase "totally symmetric" means specifically $M_{\sigma (abcdijk)} = M_{abcdijk}$, where $\sigma (abcdijk)$ means any permutation of the indices $abcdijk$. I really thought that this was clear in the question, but based on all the comments, I am realizing that this is not the case.

Comment: Storing data in a dict will cause the memory overhead to be huge: certainly 450 GiB per 7D array (2 Python objects per item). But this is not actually the biggest issue : the Python garbage collector will take a HUGE amount of time to collect the billion objects in the dictionary during full collection freezing the program for a very long time. Not to mention the time to fill/iterate this data structure... Internal dict hashing will cause massive cash trashing, that is a lot of overhead.

Comment: @JérômeRichard And, yes, I have already run smaller simulations with only 5 axes and I have managed to store the data using 16bit numbers in about 0.8 gigabytes without using symmetry. And, that simulation does stall the program for about 2 seconds at load time, but I am using an array and not a dictionary.

Comment: The key is certainly to flatten the array (without hashing for sake of performance, or with a kind of "locality-sensitive hashing") and but this is not simple in 7D. You can wrap this in a custom class. Once done, Numpy functions will not be useful anymore (like on Scypy's sparse matrices). I am not sure Python is suited for that, but if performance matters (certainly), then you certainly need to compile the target class (with Cython or Numba). Regarding the ressource consumption, I advise you to use a lower level language to avoid wasting precious resources.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thank you for the analysis. This is definitely good advice, which I have been trying to avoid taking up to now since my programming skills are quite weak and my only other language is C++ (which I haven't written anything in it for about a decade).

Comment: Super-symmetric tensors can generally be reduced in order to lower-dimensionality state spaces.  Most common example is the piola-Kirchoff Stress-strain tensor that for orthotorpic materials is a super-symmetric 3x3x3x3 (81-element) tensor that is usually represented by a 6x6 (36-element) 2D tensor through change of basis.  Applying the properties involved to a general tensor isn't particularly straightforward though.

Answer (score 1):

Exploit the symmetry in this problem.
Define a function

```
def hash(dims, indices):
```

which always returns a non-negative integer less than 1e8.

When accessing your numpy array, always do so via the hash function,
so we're storing fewer than 1e8 distinct entries.
At that point it likely doesn't matter
whether the underlying numpy storage is sparse or dense.

Often we seek to minimize the number of collisions
produced by a hash function.
But here, we take advantage of the fact that
similar (symmetric) coordinates will hash
to the identical value.

Comment: It's a little unclear how you'd define this hash function in such a way that unrelated coordinates don't hash to the same bucket. e.g. how do you prevent (1, 2) and (1,3) from hashing to the same bucket? Or is the idea to write code which can tolerate the collisions?

Comment: @NickODell, the OP has been rather vague about the nature of the symmetry inherent in his problem. So I left it to him to suitably define the hash function. The notion of "let's hash it!" seemed to be what was missing from his problem description. If 2D upper triangular was the problem domain of interest, then the hash function would simply swap x <-> y if x less than y, and report crc32(x, y) or whatever's convenient. There are techniques for devising a perfect hash, but they do not yet seem relevant to OP's inquiry. Collisions happen -- call them "noise".

Comment: This seems quite straightforward. Let me see if I get the gist of this solution: Basically, I would store one instance of each array value in (for instance) a list and then access the values as needed by assigning each of the unique index combinations from the array a value between 0 and the length of the list. This way, I have a many-to-one mapping between permutations of indices and the value that they share in common. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @Geoffrey it sounds like that would use more storage than intended. Let N = 50 choose 7 = 99_884_400. Using "simple 2D upper triangular" I intend to encode symmetry by conditionally swapping x <-> y, so after that transform we're guaranteed to have x >= y, thereby collapsing one half of the space into the other half. Now to efficiently map that reduced support to an array A we hash like this: A[crc32(x, y) % N] = value_to_be_stored. The CRC gives a number 0 to four billion, and modulo N squishes that back down to being array sized. SHA3 is also a nice hash. Dealing with symmetry is up to you.

Comment: Also, for big vectors avoid [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list), since it makes you pay object overhead for each stored number, plus the overhead of a 64-bit pointer for each number. Prefer python [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) or numpy [ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.html). They are far more efficient, plus they can be read ~ 3X as fast due to being cache friendly and can be scanned with no random reads. Additionally, pyarrow can conveniently store an ndarray in compressed .parquet file format.

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification. I'm not sure that this method with crc32 will work since multiple crc32 outputs will have the same remainder modulo N. I've tried both what I described in my comment (using an array instead of a list) and the best that I can understand from your comment, and the latter used too much memory (as you predicted) and the former was not providing unique indices as I described.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I don't know what your symmetry setup is. Hashing is just a standard [CS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science) technique for squishing a large support into a small one. As you observe, collisions can be an issue for some applications. Adding e.g. 50% unused RAM will reduce the collision rate, but ["birthday"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) says some will still remain. Sounds like you want (A.) an external storage setup, using disk rather than RAM, and (B.) a 1:1 Cantor diagonalization mapping from symmetric 7-space down to 1-dimensional space.

Comment: So I found a fairly inelegant solution that seems to work within the memory constraints. I create 2 1-D arrays: one with the data and another of equal length containing 7-digit integers in base-50 corresponding in the obvious way to the 7-tuple identifiers for the data. These integers fit comfortably into 64 bits. To retrieve the data, I first convert the 7-tuple into the corresponding base-50 number, do a reverse lookup for the location of that number in the second array, and finally go to that same location in the first array where the data is kept. It is a touch slow, but it works.